# Combining moderator variables in meta-regression

Tags: meta-analysis, meta-regression, metafor

I have a meta-analysis type dataset of compiled information from primary studies; including hazard ratio's and confidence intervals together with predictors (i.e. "moderators" in the context of meta analysis) such as treatment, cancer type, outcome metric etc. The objective is to compute pooled effects for pre-specified select combinations of moderators (NOT all combinations). So I was going to use the approach outline in:

https://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/tips:comp_two_independent_estimates

where one can fit a multilevel model with terms for the moderators (i.e. predictors).

If obtaining the pooled effects for the select combinations is the only objective, is it reasonable to define a new single categorical variable which define the unique combinations of moderators that were requested (let's call the derived variable "subset")? Then this is just modelled as a single categorical term (series of dummy variables) in the model. So equivalent to running lots of separate meta analyses on these subsets, but using a single model with subset as a moderator (plus random intercept and slope). The reason I am hesitant is that this involves merging / combining the moderator variables which I believe is often wasteful in statistical modelling, but I think that it may be appropriate in this context. Any guidance / advice on whether this can be justified and why / why not would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!